# HTML form fails to submit

Tags: html, forms

I was given a task to re-use an HTML form that had been already implemented on a company website.

All the form does is: grabs some personal info input and sends it to the processing script.

The task I have is to create a page hosted locally on iPad, opened on mobiel Safari. That page should then send form values to the processing script hosted on a web server.

I made the exact copy of the form, and yet for some reason, my copy doesn't work: no values are received by the script.

Here's the code of the form (minus a few countries on the list, for the sake of brevity):

```
<form id="contact_form" action="http://mycompany.formprocessor.com/process/" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">          
    <fieldset>

        <h3>1. Personal information</h3>
        <div>
            <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
            <input class="required" name="first_name" id="first_name" type="text" tabindex="10" value="" />
        </div>

        <div>       
            <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
            <input class="required" name="last_name" id="last_name" type="text" tabindex="20" value="" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input class="required" name="email" id="email" type="text" tabindex="30" value="" />
        </div>          
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <h3>2. Contact information</h3>

        <div>       
            <label for="phone">Phone</label>
            <input class="required" name="phone" id="phone" type="text" tabindex="40" value="" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="street_address">Street Address</label>
            <input name="street_address" id="street_address" type="text" tabindex="50" value="" />

            <label><em>(continued)</em></label>
            <input name="address2" id="address2" type="text" tabindex="60" value=""  />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="city">City</label>
            <input name="city" id="city" type="text" tabindex="70" value="" />
        </div>

        <div>       
            <label for="state">State/Province</label>
            <input name="state" id="state" type="text" tabindex="80" value="" />
        </div>

        <div>       
            <label for="zip">Zip/Postal</label>
            <input class="required" name="zip" id="zip" type="text" tabindex="90" value="" />
        </div>


        <div>
            <label>Your Country:</label>
            <select name="country" id="country" tabindex="93">
                <option value="0">Select...</option>
                <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
                <option value="Antarctica">Antarctica</option>
                <option value="Bouvet Island">Bouvet Island</option>
                <option value="Cocos (Keeling) Islands">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
                <option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option>
                <option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option>
                <option value="Faroe Islands">Faroe Islands</option>
                <option value="Greenland">Greenland</option>
                <option value="Heard Island and McDonald Islands">Heard Island and McDonald Islands</option>
                <option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option>
                <option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
                <option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
                <option value="Niue">Niue</option>
                <option value="Poland">Poland</option>
                <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
                <option value="Romania">Romania</option>
                <option value="South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands">South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
                <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
                <option value="Togo">Togo</option>
                <option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
            </select>   
        </div>  
    </fieldset>

    <div class="submit">
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"  /> 
    </div>
</form>
```

What should I do to make this form work?

Comment: What do you mean with "hosted locally on iPad"?

Comment: I'm quite sure that isn't valid HTML; but what does happen when you click submit? Anything? White page? Nothing?

Comment: is your Ipad connected to the internet?

Comment: @Baszz Same origin policy applies mostly to scripts. You can do form POST requests to "foreign" sites just fine.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid You say that this isn't valid HTML. What mistake did you find?

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus You are so right.

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus I should have said "well formed".

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Ah okay. Well, it is only a fragment.

Comment: By "hosted locally on iPad", @w4rumy, I mean that the html page is actually located on iPad, not on a web server. Or, if not not iPad, let;s say it's on my computer (it doesn't transfer values either from iPad or from a computer).

Comment: When I click "submit", @BurhanKhalid, I am redirected to the script, which outputs the XML page that says that the values had not been submitted to any of the XML tags.

Comment: Your HTML works. http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/YsJKQ/ AND is valid HTML assuming a valid doctype `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><title> ...</title></head><body>...</body></html>`

Comment: Could you post your PHP code as the answer, @mplungjan, please? It's an excellent code, I'd appreciate it very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html works - especially if you have it wrapped in

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>...</title>
    </head>
    <body>...</body>
  </html>
```

I tested it using this php:

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
print('<pre>');
print_r($_REQUEST);
print('</pre>');
?>
```

I get [**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/YsJKQ/)

```
POST
Array
(
    [first_name] => 
    [last_name] => 
    [email] => 
    [phone] => 
    [street_address] => 
    [address2] => 
    [city] => 
    [state] => 
    [zip] => 
    [country] => 0
 )
```

Comment: Thank you so very much, @mplungjan. By the way, I'm impressed with your website.

Comment: :) Thanks! It is as they say: “The shoemaker's son always goes barefoot” - I wanted to upload all my code to a comprehensive DB there, but never get around to it.

Comment: That would be a very valuable resource.

Comment: WOW, that's a lot of stuff. Thank you very much, Michel!

Comment: Great snippets! Thanks again!